# Why Is Xamarin.iOS crashing when I'm trying to acquire video

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

HI All I am trying to convert some objective C Code to C# but the App crashes when ever It hits *AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice*

```
            if (_defaultDevice != null)
            {
                NSError error;
               var _defaultDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(_defaultDevice, out error);
```

the Output is not helping ..

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x10116c6f8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C68E54FC-7A9C-4AC3-BA8C-32E04DAD78BF/Flower.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1011628f0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C68E54FC-7A9C-4AC3-BA8C-32E04DAD78BF/Flower.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x10116bc40 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C68E54FC-7A9C-4AC3-BA8C-32E04DAD78BF/Flower.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : sigabrt_signal_handler
    0x1e0edfd50 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1c0ddc594 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1c0ddc5c4 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1d8629800 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
    0x1d8624718 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
    0x1d8627394 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
    0x1e0f20cc8 - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1e0f15004 - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : <redacted>
    0x188113368 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1880cc38c - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1880c3494 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1e0eeaf70 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_wqthread
    0x1e0eeaaa4 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : start_wqthread

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1c0dda048):0x1c0dda038  c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 30 41 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .._..._.0A......
0x1c0dda048  e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 9f 65 ff 97  ...T.{.......e..
0x1c0dda058  bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6  .....{...._..._.
0x1c0dda068  90 32 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9  .2.........T.{..
```

has anyone got any idears what is happening ?

Regards Christian Stœr

here is more code

```
public BFCodeReader()
        {
            _metadataObjectTypes = AVMetadataObjectType.QRCode;
            SetUp();
        }

        private AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer _previewLayer;

        private AVCaptureSession _session;

        private AVCaptureMetadataOutput _metadataOutput;

        private AVCaptureDevice _defaultDevice;

        private AVMetadataObjectType _metadataObjectTypes;

        private AVCaptureDeviceInput _defaultDeviceInput;

        private AVCaptureDevice _frontDevice;

        private AVCaptureDeviceInput _frontDeviceInput;


        // this maybe wrong but I need to return a handle
        public IntPtr Handle => this.Handle; //_session.Handle; 

        public IBFCodeSCanner ScannerDelegate;

        private void SetUp()
        {

            
            _defaultDevice = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaType.Video);
            if (_defaultDevice != null)
            {
                NSError error;
                try
                {
                    _defaultDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(_defaultDevice, out error);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                _metadataOutput = new AVCaptureMetadataOutput();

                _session = new AVCaptureSession();

                _previewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(_session);

                AVCaptureDevice[] devices = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
                foreach (var device in devices)
                {
                    if (device.Position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front)
                    {
                        _frontDevice = device;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(_frontDevice != null)
                {
                    _frontDeviceInput = new AVCaptureDeviceInput(_frontDevice, out _);
                }
                ConfigureComponents();
            }
            
        }
```

that is all the code

PS class is BFCodeReader
and the ConfigureComponente is empty at the moment

Comment: Use `try catch` to see what is happening, and please provide the complete code so that we can try to reproduce the issue for further troubleshooting.

Comment: try catch catch never gets executed

Comment: The app still crash after add `Try-Catch` block ?

Comment: I did and it never gets to the catch it abends so badly that the catch doesn't get executed

Comment: I can't be able to reproduce your problem , if possible could you provide us a baisc, minimal project to test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the Info.plist helped me overcome this today.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Introduction to Manual Camera Controls.</string>
```